# Problem with the connectness of some set

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are topological groups and $f:A \rightarrow B$, $g: B\rightarrow C$ are homomorphisms such that $f$ is injective and $g$-surjective. Is it true that if $A$ and $C$ are connected then $B$ is connected?

Comment: Are maybe known some additional conditions on groups $A,C$ or homomorphisms $f,g$ that ensures connectedness of B$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $A$ be any connected topological group, $B=A\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ with discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and put $C=A$. Then

$$\iota:A\to B$$
$$\iota(x)=(x, 0)$$

is injective (as an embedding into first coordinate) while

$$\pi:B\to C$$
$$\pi(x, y)=x$$

is surjective (as a projection onto first coordinate). They are both continous homomorphisms. But $B$ is not connected. It has two connected components, namely $A\times\{0\}$ and $A\times\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another counterexample . . .

Let 
\begin{align*}
B &= \{(x,y) \in R^2 \mid x,y \ne 0\}\; \text{(with component-wise multiplication)}\\[6pt]
A &= \{(x,y) \in R^2 \mid x,y > 0\}\; \text{(as a subgroup of B)}\\[6pt]
C &= A\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Let $f\,\text{:}\,A \to B$, $\;g\,\text{:}\,B \to C$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= (x,y)\\[6pt]
g(x,y) &= (|x|,|y|)\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Then

- $f,g$ are homomorphisms.

  $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective.

  $A,C$ are connected, but $B$ is not connected.